# Laravel 9: FormRequest::withValidator method throwing error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-formrequest

I have a `FormRequest` with the `withValidator()` method (which I copied exactly as it is in the Laravel documentation), but when executing the class an error is returned.

Class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Conversation;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreConversationRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'type' => 'required|in:text,media',
            'text' => 'required_if:type,text|string',
            'medias' => 'required_if:type,media|array',
            'medias.*' => 'file|max:5120|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,pdf,mp3,mp4',
            'phone' => 'required|numeric',
            'conversation' => 'required|exists:conversations,id',
        ];
    }
    
    /**
     * Configure the validator instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
     * @return void
     */
    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        $validator->after(function ($validator) {
            if ($this->somethingElseIsInvalid()) {
                $validator->errors()->add('field', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Method App\Http\Requests\Conversation\StoreConversationRequest::somethingElseIsInvalid does not exist.
```

I tried replacing `$this` with `$validator` but the error persists:

```
Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::somethingElseIsInvalid does not exist.
```

Comment: It's not obvious, but that's supposed to be a custom function, not a stock function. If you don't need to do any additional validation, just remove that function.

Comment: Certainly.
I just added the code from the documentation to test, then this error came. So I haven't even started adding my code.

Comment: @Lucas `somethingElseIsInvalid()` is a test function that it expects you to write. It's not some magical feature of Laravel that detects other errors.

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem with this:

```php
/**
 * Configure the validator instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
 * @return void
 */
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if ($validator->errors()->isNotEmpty()) {
            $validator->errors()->add('field', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
        }
    });
}
```

But I don't understand why a code in the documentation is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I quite didn't get  from where did you find this function:

```
somethingElseIsInvalid()
```

Try In this way:

```
   public function withValidator( $validator )
{

    if ( $validator->fails() ) {
        // Handle errors
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: as I said, I copied the code from the documentation. And your code didn't work.